# How would you write this linq query efficiently?

Tags: linq-to-entities

There are n companies
There are m employees
An employee can work in multiple companies

I give you a list of companies {c1,c2,...} Give me all employees that work for this companies and their name is Bob.

```
context.EmployeeSet.Where(e => e.Companies.Intersect(_companiesParam)!=null).Where(emp=>emp.Name=="Bob").ToList();
```

Searching for all employees called Bob would be really slow as the average number of employees for each company is less than 10, so I first filer by companies.

What concerns me is how should I write the .Where(e => e.Companies.Intersect(_companiesParam)!=null) more effective. Is it possible to avoid the intersect operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always write it with Any and Contains if you want to avoid the Intersect.

```
context.EmployeeSet.Where(e => e.Companies.Any(c => _companiesParam.Contains(c)) && e.Name == "Bob").ToList();
```